# how can I predict for each row in the dataframe by iterating through the rows?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, iterator, iteration

I built a BERT model and now I have a chunk that works nicely for classifying each single row in text column one by one. Pandas dataframe is like this:

```
    text
0   working add oil
1   @KristianaNKOTB you're welcome
2   is going to bed, work in the morning boo but t...
3   @sparky_habbo - uni &amp; assignments happened...
4   Can't wait to have chinese food! Still disappo...
```

The code for classifying each specific row in text column is this:

```
text = [df[0]]

pred_tokens = map(tokenizer.tokenize, text)
pred_tokens = map(lambda tok: ["[CLS]"] + tok + ["[SEP]"], pred_tokens)
pred_token_ids = list(map(tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids, pred_tokens))

pred_token_ids = map(lambda tids: tids +[0]*(data.max_seq_len-len(tids)),pred_token_ids)
pred_token_ids = np.array(list(pred_token_ids))

predictions = model.predict(pred_token_ids).argmax(axis=-1)

df = pd.DataFrame(predictions, columns = ['emotion'])
df
```

For example if we want to classify if `df.text[0]`, so `'working add oil'`, is 1 or 0 I use this code and outcome is like this:

```
    emotion
0   1
```

But now how can I predict for each row in the dataframe by iterating through the rows?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a code that demonstrates the process which can be used to predict the text in a dataframe and save it.

**input data:**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"text":['working add oil',"@KristianaNKOTB you're welcome","is going to bed, work in the morning boo but t..."]})
```

define a function. you can tweak it as per your program. you can comment my code and uncomment your code.

```
import random
def predict_emotion(input_text):
    text = input_text
    
    ''' uncomment this and remove my return statement
    pred_tokens = map(tokenizer.tokenize, text)
    pred_tokens = map(lambda tok: ["[CLS]"] + tok + ["[SEP]"], pred_tokens)
    pred_token_ids = list(map(tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids, pred_tokens))

    pred_token_ids = map(lambda tids: tids +[0]*(data.max_seq_len-len(tids)),pred_token_ids)
    pred_token_ids = np.array(list(pred_token_ids))

    predictions = model.predict(pred_token_ids).argmax(axis=-1)
    return predictions
    '''
    return_int=random.randint(1,8)
    print(f"text:{input_text},emotion:{return_int}")
    return return_int
```

call the function for each row of input text.

```
df['emotion']=df['text'].apply(predict_emotion)
```

output:
[image]

Comment: emotion must be 1 or 0, this is a classification task.
I test this code on just 3 random rows and the output is like this, there is a lot ones and zeros:

`text emotion
1 you're welcome [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
5 Prepping for auditions this afternoon. From wh... [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, ...
7 off to face my exam now [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, ...`  Image link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q8uB5vZyjEWEVfyIrRircY5S4jbVb781/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This are steps I have done: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Osh1rKnjLlZ60yHzwAMQgA7XS1YJ9EUJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: this is a problem with the model, it has 14 as output, so surely not a binary classification model. This answer was for running prediction and it works okay. pls, put a new question on the model.

Comment: I have posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67356712/text-classification-using-bert-model

Comment: thanks, I will also look at it. pls, accept this answer. thanks