# Text classification using BERT model

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification, sentiment-analysis, bert-language-model

I have built and trained the BERT model, using [this code](https://github.com/curiousily/Deep-Learning-For-Hackers/blob/master/18.intent-recognition-with-BERT.ipynb).

Now I have this data:

[image]

and using this built function to classify each row in the text column as **0** or **1**.

```
import random
def predict_emotion(input_text):
    text = input_text
    
   
    pred_tokens = map(tokenizer.tokenize, text)
    pred_tokens = map(lambda tok: ["[CLS]"] + tok + ["[SEP]"], pred_tokens)
    pred_token_ids = list(map(tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids, pred_tokens))

    pred_token_ids = map(lambda tids: tids +[0]*(data.max_seq_len-len(tids)),pred_token_ids)
    pred_token_ids = np.array(list(pred_token_ids))

    predictions = model.predict(pred_token_ids).argmax(axis=-1)
    return predictions

    df['emotion']=df['text'].apply(predict_emotion)
```

However, if I test it on just 3 random rows I am getting this array [1,0,......], instead of binary outcome: 1,0.
Does anybody know how to solve it?
[image]

Comment: You don't need to take the argmax as it is binary classification `predictions = model.predict(pred_token_ids)`

Comment: The BERT model you have referred to has 7 as output layer, and this he got because there were 7 indents. `classes = train.intent.unique().tolist()
print(classes)` , I am not sure what data you have; so try to run this statement on your data, most likely you will see 14 there. If you need binary classification, then you should have 2 there.

Comment: @simpleApp after running this code: `classes = train.intent.unique().tolist() print(classes)`, outcome is binary: `['NEGATIVE', 'POSITIVE']`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67361448/error-in-binary-outcome-after-prediction-by-bert-model